# Why have docker-compose volumes to be declared twice when not pointing to an actual folder on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

In a [docker-compose.yml file](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose), do I really need to specify the `volumes` twice; inside *and* outside a service? If yes, Why? (the docker-compose part of the doc doesn't have much information on that)

[image: docker-compose volume inside a service]

I have the **feeling** that, in the case shown here where the `myapp` volume is not explicitly a folder on the host machine, we *have* to set it twice, but if it actually *is* a folder on the host machine, specifying it only inside the `frontend` service block is enough.

In addition, when the volume is specified outside the service block, it's almost always written as `key:` without any actual value (or sometime as `key: {}`), which makes me confused.

Moreover, when I run `docker-compose down -v` it actually only applies on volumes which are not explicitly specified as a folder on the host machine, according to the doc:

```
-v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`
                        section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                        attached to containers.
```

So maybe the declaration of a volume *outside* a service is for making this volume identifiable, hence 'removable'. And on the other hand, it will never be removable if it's not set outside the service?

Comment: Volumes declared in the `docker-compose.yml` file refer to volumes managed by Docker. If you don't declare the volume outside the `services` section, that refers to a bind mount on your local filesystem. Docker will expect this mount to be in the context you provide it on the host machine. There are various reasons, performance being one of them, that you'd choose Docker volumes over bind mounts. You may have already seen this, but here's some relevant docs: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a whole bunch of questions - let's try to answer them sequentially:

**1. Do I really need to specify the volumes twice (inside and outside the services section)?**

This is not a duplicate specification: outside you **declare** the volume and inside you specify how to **mount** it into a container. A volume has an independent life cycle from services. It can be mounted by several services and it will retain data if services are restarted.

**2. When the volume is specified outside the service block, it's almost always written as key: {}**

This key-only notation is the default and does not require any driver configuration. However, if you needed to e.g. connect to NFS, you would have something like:

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/docker/example"
```

Also, please differentiate between [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and regular volumes. While regular volumes are managed independently from services (and containers), e.g. with `docker volumes list`, bind-mounts are mere mappings between the host and the container file system. They are tied to the container they are mounted to.

**3. When I run `docker-compose down -v` it actually only applies on volumes which are not explicitly specified as a folder on the host machine**

Yes, this won't remove bind mounts, since bind mounts are mere host-container filesystem mappings and therefore Docker does not create an independent volume entity for them.

For deeper understanding, please consider this excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

> Bind mounts have been around since the early days of Docker. Bind
> mounts have limited functionality compared to volumes. When you use a
> bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a
> container. The file or directory is referenced by its absolute path on
> the host machine. By contrast, when you use a volume, a new directory
> is created within Docker’s storage directory on the host machine, and
> Docker manages that directory’s contents.

Comment: Are docker volumes the folders that are created (or deleted on `down -v`) here on a Ubuntu system: `/var/lib/docker/volumes`?