# Why do I need to specify volumes twice?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/ubxnfr/docker_compose_why_do_i_need_to_specify_volumes/) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420729/why-have-docker-compose-volumes-to-be-declared-twice-when-not-pointing-to-an-act) one. And the best explanation I've found is:

> ... outside you declare the volume and inside you specify how to mount it into a container. A volume has an independent life cycle from services. It can be mounted by several services and it will retain data if services are restarted.

I still do not understand why I need to specify volumes twice, even if a volume can be mounted several times in different services. I think I just understood this topic very bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to make a programming analogy.

A volume could be thought of like a function or method. You *define* a function only one time, but you can *use* that same function many times; no matter how many times or in how many places you *use* the function, it was still only *defined* in one place.

Here, you define the volume once, e.g.:

```yaml
volumes:
  db-data:
```

In this example, there are no additional parameters, so the volume is only declared to exist. Any parameters are left to their default values. But you *could* define more properties on this volume, as needed.

```yaml
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.0.0.10,rw"
```

Now that your volume is defined, you can use it in one container, or in multiple. You would not need to specify any of these parameters again; you'd need only to specify the path to mount the volume on, in each container.

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: awesome/database
    volumes:
      - db-data:/etc/data

  bar:
    image: awesome/database
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

You'll find a similar situation with `networks`, you can define a network in the `networks:` section, and then define numerous containers that would attach to that network. Same basic idea.

Comment: So I that only for following DRY principle ?

Comment: No. If you want to use a volume in the `services` section, you have to declare it exists, in the `volumes` section. This is no different than if you want to create a network for services to use - you would create such a network in the `networks` section. My post is trying to explain why the `volumes` section exists separately, using an analogy, but it's just an analogy. The bottom line is if you want to use a volume, it has to exist; to exist you have to declare it. That is done in the `volumes` section.

Answer (score 0):

So let‘s say you have two containers of the same image and you want to reference the volume again in the second container without having to specify where the resource is locally, but mount it at a different path in the second container, that‘s when you might use this. Otherwise only specifying it once per container is enough.

Comment: I'm pretty new to docker and I don't understand what you're talking about. Can you please provide some examples ? Thank you for the answer !